# How to add Multiple Headings and elements in UIPickerView or create drop down list in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

How can i have picker view which contain:

**Heading1**

Element1

Element2

Element3

**Heading2**

Element4

Element5

Element6

and so on? In the uipickerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picker views don't have the concept of sections and headers. You would have to set up your data source yourself to insert header rows, and then those heading entries would be selectable. You'd have to write your picker view delegate to skip the heading row when the user selected it.

Comment: Hi Duncan C, thank you very much for your response, is it possible to have some coding clue ? I will highly appreciate your time.

Comment: I've never had a need to do this myself, so I don't have any code on hand to share. I'd say create a struct that has a header entry and an array of values. Then create an array of those structs and use them to feed the picker view. You'd need to write a method that would assemble the array of structs into a flat array of strings to feed the picker view data source.

Comment: To skip the headers you'd implement `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` and check to see if a header row was selected. If so you'd call `selectRow(_:inComponent:animated:)` to skip to the next/previous row. You'd need to keep track of which direction the user was coming from so you could continue moving in the same direction to skip the header.